# Is it possible to plot images in a ggplot2 plot, that don't get distorted when you save to any non-standard aspect ratio?

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, plot

I'm looking for any solution to this problem, regardless of packages used.

The problem at hand is that plotted images get distorted when you save them using `ggsave`. Let me give an example:

```
image_links = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                         image = c("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Smiling_Emoji_with_Eyes_Opened_large.png",
                                   "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Smiling_Emoji_with_Smiling_Eyes_large.png",
                                   "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Hushed_Face_Emoji_large.png",
                                   "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Disappointed_but_Relieved_Face_Emoji_large.png",
                                   "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Expressionless_Face_Emoji_large.png"))


mydata = data.frame(x = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 20),
                    y = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 5),
                    id = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 20))

mydata$y = mydata$y - 10*mydata$id

mydata = mydata %>% left_join(image_links, by='id')

g <- ggplot(mydata) + geom_image(aes(x=x, y=y, image=image), size=0.05)

ggsave(g, filename='[INSERT PATH HERE].png', width=width, height=height, dpi=300)
```

This works fine:
[image: The emoji's are displayed fine.]

The problem arises when you adjust the `width` and `height` parameters of `ggsave`, for instance because you want the x and y-axis to be in the correct proportion:

```
width = (max(mydata$x) - min(mydata$x))/10
height = (max(mydata$y) - min(mydata$y))/10

ggsave(g, filename='[INSERT PATH HERE].png', width = width, height=height, dpi=300)
```

The x and y-axis are now fine, but the images are distorted:
[image: Emojis are distorted]

This happens in ANY situation where you plot an image but the `width`/`height` aspect ratio is different than what was the original aspect ratio of the image you want to add.

I'm looking for any solution to this problem, not necessarily restricted to `ggimage`. It seems very weird to me that you can't properly add images to a ggplot, as I image it's very common for people to want to do that.

Comment: What packages are being used for this example?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I'm not sure this is possible - after all, the images in the plot come from a data frame which stores all their points and information, so shrinking naturally distorts the images. I think for what you want to be possible, geom_image should be constructed in another way (all packages I know for this work like that though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know a lot about ggsave, but this seems like an issue related to relative versus absolute units. Probably the `geom_image()` calculates positions relative to the axes, which get distorted when the axes get resized (such as within `ggsave`). For example:

```
ggplot(mydata) + geom_image(aes(x=x, y=y, image=image), size=0.05)
```

Can look like:

[image]

Or can look like:

[image]

Depending on the device window that I can resize at will.

There are two ways I can see this getting fixed, both of which will involve re-calculating the sizes of the rasters at drawtime. The easier fix will be the one below.

```
# Get plot
g <- ggplot(mydata) + geom_image(aes(x=x, y=y, image=image), size=0.05)

# Convert to gtable
gt <- ggplotGrob(g)

# Get the imagegrobs, correct slots found by trial and error
imagegrobs <- gt$grobs[[6]]$children[[3]]$children

# Re-class them to a custom, made-up class
imagegrobs <- lapply(imagegrobs, function(image) {
  class(image) <- c("fixasp_raster", class(image))
  image
})

# Put them back into the gtable
gt$grobs[[6]]$children[[3]]$children <- imagegrobs
```

So now that we have a custom class for these images, we can write a piece of code that gets executed at the time of drawing by writing a method for our class using the S3 generic `makeContent` from the grid package.

```
library(grid)
makeContent.fixasp_raster <- function(x) {
  # Convert from relative units to absolute units
  h <- convertHeight(x$height, "cm", valueOnly = TRUE)
  w <- convertWidth(x$width, "cm", valueOnly = TRUE)
  # Decide how the units should be equal
  x$height <- x$width <- unit(sqrt(h * w), "cm")
  x
}
```

Note that taking the square root of the product is improvised, I don't know if this is the optimal procedure.

When we plot the data now, we'll have a consistent size of the images, regardless of the aspect ratio:

```
grid.newpage(); grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]
[image]

The second way to fix this is to file an issue in the github page of the `ggimage` package, motivating your use case and convice them to implement something that adresses your concerns. If they want, they could make a fix at the ggproto level, so that you don't have dabble with gtables.

Comment: Ace! This works for `ggsave` as well. I'll also file an issue on github.

Comment: This is now implemented in the latest dev version of `ggimage`!

Comment: Wow that was quick!

Answer (score 1):

@teunbrand's answer has been implemented in dev version 0.2.4 of `ggimage`. You can install the latest dev version like this:

```
setRepositories(ind=1:2)
## install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("GuangchuangYu/ggimage")
```

This should fix the aspect ratio issues.

Comment: This still does not seem to work for wide images (that are wider than their height). Using version 0.2.5. Works well for high images.